# Google app engine receiving audio binary stream

Tags: perl, google-app-engine

UPDATE AFTER ANSWER: the code is now fixed and works look below for correct code

Im trying to post from a perl script (on my server) to my google app engine, and im not sure how to go about doing this on the google app engine side.

This is my perl script for testing :

```
my $audio = `cat audiotest.flac`;
my $url = "http://app.appspot.com/MainPage" #this is not the real url
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $response = $ua->post($url, Content_Type => "audio/x-flac; rate=16000", Content => $audio);
if ($response->is_success)
{
 print $response->content;
}
```

So that is how i send the flac binary stream, but the question is how does google app engine receive it and do something with it. This is what im attempting to do in python (but the code is not correct and / or doesnt make sense)

```
class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):  
def post(self):
    destinationURL = "http://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?xjerr=1&client=chromium&lang=en-US"
    result = urlfetch.fetch(url=destinationURL, payload= self.request.body, method=urlfetch.POST, headers={'Content-Type': 'audio/x-flac; rate=16000'})  
    self.response.out.write(result.content)
```

result is supposed to return to me the string representation of the flac audio i submitted to google's speech to text service (also known as x-webkit-speech). Any idea what i am supposed to put in the payload for the urlfetch, and how to get the result back? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're sending the audio file as the body of the request, not as part of a form, you can access it with `self.request.body`.

I'm a little confused as to why you're sending an audio file to App Engine just so it can send it to another service, though.

Comment: i will give this a try soon and let you know if it works. the reason behind this is i want to go through google's app engine so i can be appropriately billed, rather than be banned from the service all together (due to the high volume of audio files being sent)