# Retranslation audio stream with python on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, audio-streaming

I have a URL address to the audio stream, how I can retranslate it in the web with my address (myapp.appspot.com)?
Let me explain why I need it:
I have a very narrow channel, and will not stand many connections, so I have to do it with GAE
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make long running external calls with App Engine. Maximum deadline (task queue and cron job handler) for UrlFetch is 10 minutes. So, I think it is not possible.

Comment: А если все же попробовать, как примерно будет выглядеть код не подскажете? =)

Comment: Не получится попробовать. Что бы этот поток потом отдавать клиенту - нужно держать постоянное соединение, что невозможно с лимитами GAE. Посмотрите лучше в сторону других платформ. GAE для стриминга никак не подойдет.

Comment: Просто я прочитал этот пост [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670512/google-app-engine-receiving-audio-binary-stream) и мне показалось это возможным. Не подскажете, в каком направлении искать?

Comment: Вы можете скачать аудио файл, сохранить в blobstore и затем отдавать его пользователям. Это решит вашу проблему с узким каналом. Но это не будет стримом в реальном времени.