# Is it possible to stream data to Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, streaming

Is it possible to stream data, specifically video, to Google App Engine?

I've looked at channels, but that seems to be between my GAE app and Google servers, not clients and my GAE app.

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670512/google-app-engine-receiving-audio-binary-stream), but although it says it's receiving a stream, it looks like it's using a post.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by 'stream'?  For most applications you want to POST data to GAE.

Comment: In this situation I'm trying to stream video while it is being recorded.  I don't want to wait until the video is complete, and then upload the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can only upload data to GAE using HTTP POST.

You can either stream your file as one long HTTP POST, or break it up, send it as multiple POST requests, and reconstruct it on the server side.

You probably want to do the latter, in case you get disconnected, you don't have to resend all the data again.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  Rats.  I'll wait and hope someone else comes up with something, if nothing comes up, I'll accept your answer.  Do you know of any libraries that outline the second method you described?

Comment: The first way would be easier.  Do a search on chunked transfer encoding (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).  A quick google search for the latter showed this: https://github.com/stholmes/Morsels#readme.  I highly recommend using Google to search for things.

Comment: you have a 60 second limit anyway before your handler returns an error. GAE is not for this.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't apply for the Blobstore upload.  I haven't seen a published timeout for Blobstore uploads though.